# How to pass nested JSON data to a React component as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and React and am not sure how to do this. I have a set of JSON data, as such:

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Smith',
    status: 'Active',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Joe Blow',
    status: 'Active',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Jane Smith',
    status: 'Active',
  },
];
```

I want to send this data to a component I am building:

```
return <userList data={users}/>;
```

But from there, on the component it's self, I am unsure of how to retrieve the data from the `data` prop (to say console.log it or use it in a loop).

```
interface userListProps {
  data: [];
}

console.log(data);
```

Would anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: *Actual* component code would help here so we can see what you're working with and what you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return <userList data={users}/>;
```

then in your child component:

```
interface userListProps {
  data: [];
}

const UserList = ({data}: UserListProps) => {
  return <div>
    {data.map(user, index) =>
      <div key={`user-${index}`}>
        {user.name}
      <div>
    }
  <div>
}
```

You can retrieve the data as you want inside of the map method with, for example, a component User who takes an object "user" in Props.

Answer (score 1):

If the object shape of the 'users' are always the same, you would define a User interface and pass that around:

```
export interface IUser {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  status: 'Active' | 'Inactive';
}
```

And you would use that to define your 'users' variable: (`const users: IUser[] = [....]`). You can also use that interface in your props-interface.

```
import { IUser } from '..';

interface IUserListProps {
  data: IUser[];
}
```

The reason why your current solution isn't working, is because you're telling `data` in `userListProps` to be just an array. So this would only work if you would do `<UserList data={[]} />`.

You would define `UserList` as:

```
const UserList: React.FC<IUserListProps> = (props) => {
  // props.data is of type 'IUser[]'.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing it correctly but you haven't showed the code so that we can see how you intend to use it. I'm guessing but something like this should work

```
const userList = ({ data }) => { // this is the way to pass props in a functional component

  return (
     <div>
       {data.map((user) => <div> {user.name} </div> )} 
     </div>
  ) 
}
```

that's if you want to show just the users name, of course you can display whatever you wish

of course it might make more sense to call your prop `users` and pass it like so: `return <userList data={users}/>;`

so when mapping over it, you can `.map` over users, which is more readable and clear what you're mapping over